# Spring security: allow a few pages to be displayed in iframe

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I support a website that uses Spring Security (5.3.3.RELEASE). The site can't be displayed in iframe in other sites because of the following configuration

```
<security:headers>
  <security:frame-options policy="SAMEORIGIN"/>
</security:headers>
```

Now I am asked to allow a few pages to be displayed in iframe in ANY other sites (not a specific list of sites). I looked at the Spring documentation, and it appears that I can add a bean in the following way:

```
<security:headers>
  <security:frame-options policy="SAMEORIGIN" ref="bean_id"/>
</security:headers>
```

I am not able to find info about what interface or methods the bean (bean_id) must implement or whether it can be used to decide what pages are frameable. Any help or example is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The interface is of type `AllowFromStrategy`. But that interface is deprecated since the ALLOW-FROM is an obsolete directive that no longer works in modern browsers, [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options). The alternative is to use [CSP: frame-ancestors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors).

Spring Security has support for the `Content-Security-Policy` header. You can [rely on the `DelegatingRequestMatcherHeaderWriter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/headers.html#headers-delegatingrequestmatcherheaderwriter) implementation to add the headers only to specific pages, like so:

```xml
<http>
    <!-- ... -->

    <headers>
        <header ref="headerWriter"/>
    </headers>
</http>

<beans:bean id="headerWriter"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.DelegatingRequestMatcherHeaderWriter">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher"
            c:pattern="/page-with-csp"/>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.ContentSecurityPolicyHeaderWriter"/>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your input! In my site's configuration, I am not able to find the use of ALLOW-FROM, which may explain why the bean I created (implementing AllowFromStrategy) never got called.  Besides, the frameable pages on the site should be able to be displayed in any site. Not sure whether a bean of AllowFromStrategy is helpful.

Comment: Use the `XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter` with the `DelegatingRequestMatcherHeaderWriter` to allow specific pages to be framed, this should be a good option